# Excel - Remove AutoFilter from a Single Column

Tags: excel, filter, autofilter

I have a table similar to this example:

[image]

The hyperlinks in column B and C link to a top and bottom .jpg file for the PCB.

As you can see, the header for the "Picture" column merges over columns B and C. However, only one filter dropdown is displayed. Which column is actually being filtered, B or C?

It turns out that only column B is filtered and column C is ignored:

[image]

Further notice that the text data in column B is the same causing the filter criteria to offer only "Select All" or "Top" which, if selected, produces the same results.

Since this filter is absolutely worthless, I would like to remove the filter dropdown from the merged columns B and C.

I can place a filter on column A or column D but not both. After placing a filter on column A, placing a filter on column D removes the filter from column A, and vice versa. I have not found a way to remove the filter from columns B and C while leaving columns A and D filtered.

Searching for a solution to this issue has shown that there is a lot of confusion with the terms "remove", "clear" and "delete". They all seem to address the filter criteria and not the filter mechanism itself.

Any assistance would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Apply filter to column A, then select column D only and make it a table (Insert > Table). Now both A and D will have filter while B (and C) will be excluded

Comment: This works, EXCEPT, it runs into another issue I'm having with filters. My header consists of rows 1 and 2 merged together for some columns. If I select the columns I want to filter on, the filter dropdown is placed in bottom right corner of row 1, not the bottom right corner of row 2, the bottom right corner of the merged cells.

To get around this I have to unmerge the header cells, select the cells in row 2, apply the filter, then remerge the double height column header cells. The filter dropdown remains in the lower right corner of row 2.

Comment: But when I try and insert a table for that column there appears to be no way, with the header merged or unmerged, to get the filter dropdown in row 2. In fact, every scenario that I tried ended up unmerging the header rows. The method that did work, placing the filter dropdown in row 2 would not let me remerge rows 1 and 2 as I was able to with the initial filter placement.

Answer (score 0):

I run into this a lot.  What I typically do is add a row above the current row 1 (your row 1 becomes row 2), break the new merged B2:C2 into separate columns, and use row 1 as a super-header for the columns.

This way you're still preserving the best filtering functionality you can and you're disregarding the merged header that - as you noted - offers no meaningful filtering support.  Might not be exactly what you're looking for but thought it might help!

[image]

Comment: Had this set up at first but thought the redundant header title and hyperlink texts were redundant. Not really looking to disregard the superfluous filter dropdowns, looking to get rid of them.